# Waterline how to make reverse index

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

i have a huge timeseries collection on mongodb using sails.js and waterline.

I've found out that if change my index to reverse, it improves my query times in 40%.

Is it possible to implement a reverse index on my model? Or if it is not. Does it have a workaround that i can use that sails or grunt to setup for me when waterline is building my models?

"A document that contains the field and value pairs where the field is the index key and the value describes the type of index for that field. For an ascending index on a field, specify a value of 1; for descending index, specify a value of -1."

Documentation for index on mongodb website:
[Mongodb: Create Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sails-hook-mongoat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-mongoat) package to add advanced mongo indexing options for your sails models.

The usage is very simple:

```
// api/models/MyModel.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    myDate: {
      type: 'date',
      required: true
    }
  },
  indexes: [
    {
      attributes: {
        myDate: -1
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

You can also use [Mongo Index Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types):

```
  // [...]
  indexes: [
    {
      attributes: {
        myDate: -1
      },
      options: {
        unique: true
        expireAfterSeconds: 60
      }
    }
  ]
  // [...]
```